# How do I increase the size of a rectangle if a key is pressed?

Tags: python, pygame

Using pygame, I'm trying to create a simple mechanic which will increase a rectangle in the top right of my code, in this case it is a health bar. For now I want to make the bar increase everytime the button 'x' is clicked. Here is my code:

```
    DISPLAYSURF = DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 550), 0, 32)

    heatBar = [45, 30]
    hbPosition = [45, 30]
    # Main game loop
    while True:
        heatBar.insert(0, list(hbPosition))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
        #Heat Bar (Tap x to increase)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_x:
                for pos in heatBar:
                    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, GREEN, 
                    pygame.Rect(pos[0],pos[1],10,50))
```

The pygame.Rect on the last line is part of the line previous to it.
Anyway, I've tried to add various things and comment out things but I just can't seem to get it to work. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of a health bar:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

w, h = 400, 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))

health = 0

while True:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    if pygame.event.poll().type == pygame.QUIT: pygame.quit(); break
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_x]:
        health += 0.1

    pygame.draw.rect(screen,
                     (100, 240, 100),
                     pygame.Rect(0, 0, health, 35
    ))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

**EDIT(added extra features):**

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

w, h = 400, 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))

# I decided to go for a maxhealth type thing here,
health = 100

while True:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    # VVV This line polls pygames events and checks if it a QUIT event,
    if pygame.event.poll().type == pygame.QUIT: pygame.quit(); break

    # This relies on the previous line being called, or else it won't update,
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    # I added `Z` for adding to the health too,
    if keys[pygame.K_x] and health > 0:
        health -= 0.1
    if keys[pygame.K_z] and health < 100:
        health += 0.1

    # The tint value is multiplied by 2.55 to map 0-100 to 0-255. Try it yourself(algebra): 255/100 = 2.55,
    tint = 255 - (health * 2.55)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,
                     (tint, 255 - tint, 0),
                     pygame.Rect(0, 0, health, 35
    ))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Unfortunently because of how `tint` works, the middle range looks like a ugly brownish colour.

Also I would highly recommend you make your game with `classes`, they are much more uniform, and they are great for making large scale projects.

Here's a nice link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDa-Z5JzLYM

**EDIT(fixing brownish colour):**

To fix the brownish colour, change this line:

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen,
                (tint, 255 - tint, 0),
                pygame.Rect(0, 0, health, 35
))
```

To,

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen,
                (min(255, tint * 2), min(255, 335 - tint), 0),
                 pygame.Rect(0, 0, health, 35
))
```

*NOTE:* Using `min(255, ...)` will effectively make sure that the value does not exceed `255`, because as long as the number is less than `255` it will return the number, otherwise it will return `255`. Multiplying the `tint` by two is basically offsetting it, and the `335 - tint` is to offset the other one too, you can change `335` to another number to change where the yellow is in the health bar :)

Comment: Thanks so much! Additionally, I was wondering why the code doesn't work without the if pygame.event.poll()... line, since it doesn't seem to affect what is happening next

Comment: Okay so I have a tiny problem which I was wondering how to fix. I'm trying to make the bar get more red as it goes, so I added this to the code::                                                                                                        color= pygame.Color(0, 255, 0)
if color.r < 254:
    color.r += 2
if color.g > 1:
    color.g -= 2                                                                                                         I changed the (100, 240, 100) to color, but it's still not working. It just prints a green bar.

Comment: You have keen eyes! If you do not have `pygame.event.poll()` it will not update `pygame.key.get_pressed()`, since `pygame.key.get_pressed()` relies on polling the events first, alternatively you could do what you did in your example. As for the colouring, look at my updated answer.

Comment: @TejasK The `pygame.event.poll()` function is also needed since [you need to call one event function each couple of seconds for the OS to not think your game has frozen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44254458/pygame-needs-for-event-in-pygame-event-get-in-order-not-to-crash/44256668#44256668). However, in this case I would use `pygame.event.get()` instead and create an event loop since polling only handles one event. If more than one event is created each frame then the event queue will build up and crash the game.

Comment: How exactly does the ;break help it function?

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for clearing things up! I'm definitely going to try tweaking this and using it in my game

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to increase the color's red or green value, since this could possibly eliminate the brown color. I tried doing color.r and color.g for the respective red and green values but it's not working

Comment: Alright, so logically thinking, the reason it goes brown, is because when `r` is halfway and `g` is halfway it looks brown. However, when `r` is at 255 and `g` is at 255 it looks yellow, much better! So we need to let `r` get to 255 before we subtract from `g`. I'll update my answer for the solution. Remember `r` = `red`, `g` = `green` :)