# Pygame window freezes when it opens

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm learning how to use pygame, and I'm just trying to open up a window for the game I'm creating.

The program compiles fine, and I tried drawing a circle to see if that would change anything but in both scenarios I still just get a blank window that freezes. My computer has plenty of storage space and only 2 applications open, and yet this is the only application that is freezing.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
```

I have to force quit Python because it stops responding. I have Python version 3.7.4 and Pygame version 1.9.6.

Any advice?

Comment: It freezes because you don't handle any events. One event you should always handle is the `pygame.QUIT` event, which is when the user presses the close button on the top corner. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44256668/6486738) is more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A minimal, typical PyGame application

- needs a game loop
- has to handle the events, by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- has to update the [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) whuch represents the display respectively window, by either [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip) or [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update).

See also [Python Pygame Introduction](https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/PygameIntro.html)

Simple example, which draws a red circle in the center of the window: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-MinimalApplicationLoop](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-MinimalApplicationLoop#main.py)</kbd>

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

# main application loop
run = True
while run:

    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # clear the display
    window.fill(0)

    # draw the scene   
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 0, 0), (250, 250), 100)

    # update the display
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Thank you! My program works now. I know this was a very basic question so I appreciate you being patient with me since I'm new to Python :)

Comment: I tried your code and when i try to close the window in the X button, it always freezes! I'm using Python 3.7.7 and Pygame 1.9.6 on Thonny 3.2.7. Actually all the pygame codes that i tried so far, it happends the same thing!!!