# SDL2 applications do not work correctly in Xmonad

Tags: c, haskell, sdl, sdl-2, xmonad

Programs using [SDL2](http://wiki.libsdl.org/FrontPage), for instance games built with [pygame](https://pygame.org/) and the [Mednafen](https://mednafen.github.io/) emulator, do not work correctly with the default [Xmonad](https://xmonad.org/) configuration. When they are started in fullscreen mode, their window isn't shown. Here is a minimal reproducible example of an SDL2 program that fails to show its window:

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  SDL_Window *window;
  SDL_Surface *screen;
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
  window = SDL_CreateWindow("Example Window",
                            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                            640, 480,
                            SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN
                            );
  screen = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
  SDL_FillRect(screen, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 255, 0, 0));
  SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
  SDL_Delay(3000);
  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;
}
```

You can compile this program with the command `cc main.c -o main -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/SDL2 -lSDL2`.

Here is a minimal xmonad configuration file that reproduces the problem. Note that I am using xmonad v0.15 and SDL v2.0.14.

```hs
import XMonad

main = xmonad $ def {
  modMask = mod4Mask
  }
```

If everything is correct, this program should show a window of 640 by 480 pixels with a red background for 3 seconds, then exit. However, the only way I can get this to work with Xmonad is by specifying the following `manageHook`:

```hs
import XMonad

main = xmonad $ def {
  modMask = mod4Mask,
  manageHook = composeAll [className =? "main" --> doIgnore]
  }
```

Currently, there are many such exceptions in my Xmonad configuration to make SDL2 programs work on a per-app basis. This is annoying, especially because SDL1.2 applications - most notably [DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/) - do not have this problem.

So, my questions are:

- Is this a problem with SDL or with Xmonad?
- What is the cause of this issue?
- How can I rewrite the program above to work correctly under Xmonad?

Comment: Im not an expert at SDL2 by any means, but I think SDL (not SDL2) runs off a surface as a screen and SDL2 runs off an ```SDL_Renderer```? Have you tried with a renderer instead of a surface?

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the issue, and it seems to be working fine here: I get a 640x480 window upscaled to fullscreen just in the way you describe. You might want to specify which versions of xmonad and xmonad-contrib you are using and add your xmonad.hs (or a minimal version thereof that reproduces the issue) to the question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort! I have updated the post with version numbers and a minimal xmonad configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't have much to say about the details of what's going on, I apparently succeeded in reproducing your issue by poking at my own `xmonad.hs`. After removing the call to [`ewmh`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.16/docs/src/XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops.html#ewmh) from it, running your program resulted in an empty fullscreen window, rather than a red one. That being so, changing your minimal configuration to...

```hs
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops

main = xmonad $ ewmh def {
  modMask = mod4Mask
  }
```

... will likely fix the issue.

While you're at it, you'll probably want to enable the additional fullscreen support offered by `XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops`, which some applications require to work correctly. Here's how it looks like with *xmonad-contrib* 0.16...

```hs
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops

main = xmonad $ ewmh def {
  modMask = mod4Mask,
  handleEventHook = handleEventHook def <+> fullscreenEventHook
  }
```

... and with post-0.16 versions, such as recent builds from GitHub, following a recommendation from [a changelog entry](https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad-contrib/blob/b3316c2e3498f206747c1cd8a94af42e70e16aad/CHANGES.md#breaking-changes):

```hs
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops

main = xmonad $ ewmhFullscreen $ ewmh def {
  modMask = mod4Mask,
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I could have never figured this out myself! You are right, the C example program now runs correctly. However, I am still experiencing problems with games written in [pygame](https://pygame.org). I have updated my original question with a pygame example.

Comment: @hedgie Your pygame program behaves in the same way under Xfce, so it isn't a XMonad issue. I'm not familiar with pygame, but it seems you need a game loop for things to work properly (see, for instance, [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57642415/2751851)). Additionally, I believe you didn't mean to reassign `screen` in `screen = screen.fill((255,0,0))`. I suggest asking a separate question about those issues, if need be.

Comment: You are completely right, I have removed the pygame issue from the question. Thanks again for helping me out!